# inserting and indexing in Couchdb at the same time or consequently

Tags: couchdb

I am new to couchdb and trying to save some docs at the same time indexing them.

Currently what I do is the following:

```
app.post("/api/result-store/v1/results/:searchID", (req, res) => {
  const dbName = "test_" + req.params.searchID;
  database.checkAndCreateDatabase(dbName).then(
    db => {
      const docs = req.body.objects;
      db.bulk({ docs }).then(
        body => {
          res.send({
            writes: body.reduce((total, currentValue) => {
              return total + (currentValue.ok ? 1 : 0);
            }, 0)
          });
        },
        err => {
          res.send(err);
        }
      );
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
});
```

So all I do above is saving but no indexing. Now if I query the database like:

```
{{url}}/api/result-store/v1/results/jmeter_test_db_size_90_k?q=*:*&limit=200&counts=["qid_name", "datasource"]
```

Then the indexing will start. But this is too late since indexing takes time and the customer needs to wait and wait until the indexing is done to get the result. 
I am thinking to start indexing the data as soon as I insert the docs so saving and indexing at the same time or consequently. Is it possible at all? Any insight is appreciated

Comment: It looks like you're using a library or a custom wrapper to access `CouchDB`. Can you please provide further related information?

Comment: @uminder sure I use nano: const nano = require("nano")(
  `http://${params.USERNAME}:${params.PASSWORD}@${params.HOST_NAME}:${params.PORT}`
); which make the access to db easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `nano`, you can create the index by invoking [db.createIndex](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#dbcreateindexindexdef-callback) just after creating the database (creates an index on database fields, as specified in [CouchDB doc](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/find.html#db-index)).

Comment: Thanks I will try it and let you know about the progress

Comment: Does that start the inxeing dynamically or do we need to query the db for the indexing to start? because normally indexing start only after the first query comes in